# Crash when popping to root view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

a user reported the following crash in my iPad app.

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33200a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e373b4 pthread_kill
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e2fbf8 abort
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669da64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f8d06c _objc_terminate
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669be36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669be8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669bf5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f8bc84 objc_exception_throw
9   CoreFoundation                  0x361a3206 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
10  CoreFoundation                  0x361e2396 -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:]
11  UIKit                           0x32a622f0 -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:]
12  UIKit                           0x32a1dd94 -[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerWithTransition:]
13  UIKit                           0x32a1dd46 -[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:]
14  IW Select                       0x0001e00e -[CustomTabBarController onButtonTouchDown:] + 154
```

So apparently in some cases when that button is pressed and it's trying to switch to the root view controller, something goes wrong in the `[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:]` call.  I can't figure out what could be the problem there, does anyone have experience with this?  Since it's a crash report from a user, I can't see which exception was thrown.

Edit: here's the full report I got.

```
Incident Identifier: 105E1288-3904-4AB2-842C-95D2B6D2C0E6
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         IW Select [2124]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/5AB7092A-AF9D-4702-9712-F154BCB638E7/IW Select.app/IW Select
Identifier:      IW Select
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-04-03 22:06:56.052 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33200a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e373b4 pthread_kill
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e2fbf8 abort
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669da64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f8d06c _objc_terminate
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669be36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669be8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3669bf5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f8bc84 objc_exception_throw
9   CoreFoundation                  0x361a3206 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
10  CoreFoundation                  0x361e2396 -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:]
11  UIKit                           0x32a622f0 -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:]
12  UIKit                           0x32a1dd94 -[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerWithTransition:]
13  UIKit                           0x32a1dd46 -[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:]
14  IW Select                       0x0001e00e -[CustomTabBarController onButtonTouchDown:] + 154
15  IW Select                       0x0001d5f4 -[CustomTabBar onButtonTouchDown:] + 88
16  CoreFoundation                  0x361a856a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:]
17  UIKit                           0x32941ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
18  UIKit                           0x32941e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]
19  UIKit                           0x32941e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
20  UIKit                           0x32941b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
21  UIKit                           0x32941834 -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:]
22  UIKit                           0x32940baa -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
23  UIKit                           0x32940568 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
24  UIKit                           0x3292930c -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
25  UIKit                           0x32928c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent
26  GraphicsServices                0x327ffe70 PurpleEventCallback
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3620fa90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
28  CoreFoundation                  0x36211838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1
29  CoreFoundation                  0x36212606 __CFRunLoopRun
30  CoreFoundation                  0x361a2ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
31  CoreFoundation                  0x361a2dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
32  GraphicsServices                0x327ff418 GSEventRunModal
33  GraphicsServices                0x327ff4c4 GSEventRun
34  UIKit                           0x32953d62 -[UIApplication _run]
35  UIKit                           0x32951800 UIApplicationMain
36  IW Select                       0x00002b60 main + 44
37  IW Select                       0x00002b28 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33201fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35387094 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3538804a _dispatch_queue_invoke
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3538760a _dispatch_worker_thread2
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e3858a _pthread_wqthread
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e38bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x331fec00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x331fe758 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x362102b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36212562 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x361a2ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x361a2dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   WebCore                         0x31058292 RunWebThread
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e3730a _pthread_start
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e38bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x331fec00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x331fe758 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x362102b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36212562 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x361a2ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x361a2dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   Foundation                      0x35b4a7f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:]
7   Foundation                      0x35b3d382 -[NSThread main]
8   Foundation                      0x35baf5c6 __NSThread__main__
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e3730a _pthread_start
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e38bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33200c60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x362158f2 __CFSocketManager
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e3730a _pthread_start
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e38bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332013ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e386d8 _pthread_wqthread
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30e38bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3eb4948c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x001bafbc      r7: 0x2fdfdfa8
    r8: 0x32c1f4e8    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x3f35b9f8     r11: 0x0017eea0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfdf9c      lr: 0x30e373bb      pc: 0x33200a1c
  cpsr: 0x080f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x3bfff +IW Select armv7  <f5aa1f825f883a0565038f9f1902c658> /var/mobile/Applications/5AB7092A-AF9D-4702-9712-F154BCB638E7/IW Select.app/IW Select
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <8dbdf7bab30e355b81e7b2e333d5459b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30ae7000 - 0x30aeafff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x30aeb000 - 0x30af5fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30af7000 - 0x30b3efff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x30b3f000 - 0x30b3ffff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30b60000 - 0x30b75fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30b90000 - 0x30b93fff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x30b94000 - 0x30b95fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30b96000 - 0x30b9ffff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30c5d000 - 0x30cbbfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d3f7360687333cad987890c314ae0d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x30cbc000 - 0x30cfefff  CoreAudio armv7  <d45e275525ef3c32b36e0f1020cad705> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30d01000 - 0x30d2afff  ContentIndex armv7  <f5a3613ec5b6392995d7ed0742f7419f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x30d36000 - 0x30d36fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <68322643de8030978c862de530055bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x30d37000 - 0x30df8fff  RawCamera armv7  <4f817644f26c309abadc961569141496> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x30df9000 - 0x30dfafff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <5f077c4d204d3cd7b04452c42d41f763> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x30dfb000 - 0x30dfdfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30e04000 - 0x30e85fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <caa1846ad2583d1b84c1a15c50c126a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x30f4f000 - 0x30f55fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30f88000 - 0x30fb6fff  MIME armv7  <28e35d5e19893de6bc28463efec5222f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x30fb7000 - 0x30fbcfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x30fbd000 - 0x30fd6fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x31052000 - 0x3165dfff  WebCore armv7  <b25d7d87ebd235ecbceca611a063c73b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31694000 - 0x316a7fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x316a8000 - 0x316affff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x316b0000 - 0x31997fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <652c97e211553d4e84968a61f62a0ac5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x31a92000 - 0x31ae7fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31b5f000 - 0x31bb8fff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x31bbf000 - 0x31bd5fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9776dd6c96b531e9885bddacd2a8adb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x31c09000 - 0x31c09fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31c0a000 - 0x31c0cfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x31c0e000 - 0x31c2efff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31c2f000 - 0x31c37fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x32032000 - 0x32041fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <f258d39dc7d93faa9c9ff5cf81c5dcbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x3204a000 - 0x320d4fff  Message armv7  <1e4680ca7d4936bf9f575269b67e4402> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x3215b000 - 0x3219efff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <01a5c5442e173624bdbde3c1f4ad4665> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3232d000 - 0x3232dfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x323ee000 - 0x32421fff  iCalendar armv7  <e52c54abaab734e8b0278f358217c4b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x32533000 - 0x325f2fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32616000 - 0x32624fff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <e54fa5bf6f9333618401cdbaf665f227> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x32689000 - 0x3269bfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <8de1cf029f8132a2946ccca351dbd4fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x326a3000 - 0x326ebfff  CoreLocation armv7  <90a87c2cdf823e6892aff81a6dde3430> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3274c000 - 0x3274ffff  libgermantok.dylib armv7  <a58c5595d1ca3c2ebc77d486d46d8c4f> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
0x32750000 - 0x32752fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32760000 - 0x327a0fff  CoreMedia armv7  <0fcb3d1136d033d3acd97519c4be3ac3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x327fb000 - 0x32807fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c508734deb43352782433a290ff235bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32808000 - 0x3280bfff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3280c000 - 0x3280cfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <ffe9658cbc6e3464898da2d12f1a66d2> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x32925000 - 0x32cb2fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32cb3000 - 0x32dfffff  MediaToolbox armv7  <7b1ac06abad33dca99a29629b667f929> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32ede000 - 0x32ee1fff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x32ee2000 - 0x32f02fff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x32f11000 - 0x33032fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <54e27b8aa66c32b48ffeadadcc514331> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33033000 - 0x3306bfff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3309f000 - 0x330a2fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0479a171c00d3f629d639713acb72b5b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x33145000 - 0x331eefff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x331ef000 - 0x33206fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <29eb602b615b3c3b95722868100a2d1c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3326a000 - 0x3328afff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x333a4000 - 0x333c1fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x333c2000 - 0x333c9fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x334d1000 - 0x335d9fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3360b000 - 0x3360ffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <2c61a8f7e7bf32d890e957d768d769ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33610000 - 0x33617fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x33618000 - 0x33619fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3361a000 - 0x33689fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x336a3000 - 0x33752fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33783000 - 0x33829fff  Celestial armv7  <6a54406a081a3b5fa6b22754b013b629> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x33848000 - 0x33851fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3533c000 - 0x35349fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x35371000 - 0x35380fff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x35381000 - 0x3538efff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <6c4eeb08757b365f8429ef6747f89ad3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x356a3000 - 0x356a4fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x356a5000 - 0x356a9fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <36e96d0a7dda330281a43172d0ada49a> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x356aa000 - 0x356defff  VideoToolbox armv7  <aec2e22a2055380e82d4d0279faad0a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x356ea000 - 0x35738fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x35739000 - 0x357d6fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x357d7000 - 0x3581dfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <4319daea186b3a22b148ca78000f11ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x358e7000 - 0x359d4fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35ad9000 - 0x35ae2fff  ITSync armv7  <dc57c003aad83864827ccf95fc579563> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x35ae3000 - 0x35b1ffff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <79d00adb09de3da991ed21f48f27adb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x35b20000 - 0x35c3ffff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35c65000 - 0x35c69fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x35cd9000 - 0x35dddfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <f63386018d703534b766514e4bbbd1d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35dde000 - 0x35e8ffff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35e99000 - 0x35e9bfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c0617d2a41283cc2bff1a1d770c06f8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36076000 - 0x36190fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x36197000 - 0x36199fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3619a000 - 0x3627ffff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f643539f91f330790f112ea7150b3a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x36280000 - 0x362affff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x362b0000 - 0x362effff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <b5735b0f3dba32c087c5b58aa48ae592> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3664b000 - 0x36658fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <d454cde062983860a41694922eb5c042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x36659000 - 0x366a3fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x366bb000 - 0x36750fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3677d000 - 0x36788fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3678e000 - 0x36793fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <a19b1caf96c73568b14a1660f147ae2f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x367d1000 - 0x367d6fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <1eaf25ddd98e3a249bca536671c5819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x36837000 - 0x36839fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x3683a000 - 0x3686ffff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x368f3000 - 0x368f8fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3691f000 - 0x36926fff  WebUI armv7  <74070ad76277301fba6d3a5eb5f214b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x36930000 - 0x3695efff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x36a5f000 - 0x36a5ffff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36a70000 - 0x36a76fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36a7b000 - 0x36a80fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36bd9000 - 0x36c0cfff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x36d2c000 - 0x36d4bfff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36d4c000 - 0x36d9afff  CoreMotion armv7  <8660c1394c5c39089407c07fd7fd8b52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x36d9b000 - 0x36dcefff  StoreServices armv7  <a74659288dea34bca7a7911c19cf2c28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x36dfb000 - 0x36e0bfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36e50000 - 0x36ea1fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x36ecc000 - 0x36ef5fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36f26000 - 0x36f27fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x36f28000 - 0x36f60fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36f63000 - 0x36f73fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x36f74000 - 0x36f77fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x36f78000 - 0x36f84fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36f87000 - 0x3704bfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <f855251d90a53bdbb5d5a39fdbde6d9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3704c000 - 0x3707ffff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x37081000 - 0x3708ffff  OpenGLES armv7  <f02d1c50f0f33991adb1a2caed02eb77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x37093000 - 0x370cafff  Security armv7  <163414ba17df347ca76088015010e2c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x370d1000 - 0x37225fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x37226000 - 0x37263fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3726c000 - 0x3726dfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
```

Edit 2:

Here's the `[CustomTarBarController onButtonTouchDown:]` method:

```
- (void)onButtonTouchDown:(NSUInteger)i {
  self.selectedIndex = i;
  for (UINavigationController *_controller in self.viewControllers) {
    [_controller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code that's around that `removeObjectsInRange` call..

Comment: yan: That's being called from Apple's UIKit...

Comment: I guess the viewController array (self.viewControllers) is being modified by each pop. This could cause the crash. I believe this could be the problem because of your stacktrace: `-[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:]`

Comment: That sounds right, but the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method is part of Apple's UIKit and should work.  My question is, why isn't it?

Comment: Also please note that it seems to be working normally in most cases (as I can't reproduce the error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` without animation. I remember that once I've got crashes that have been caused by several animations at once; for example, with code like this:

```
[self.modalView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToTootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In my case I just set YES in second line to NO, and it helped.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using a **`for`** statement? Comment it out and see if that works for you.

```
- (void)onButtonTouchDown:(NSUInteger)i {
    self.selectedIndex = i;
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How would that work?  I need to pop to the root controller for each tab in the bar.

Comment: no, what I mean was remove **for(){}**, leaving `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` method only.

Comment: And which `UINavigationController` would I use?

Comment: Whatever the beginning of the stack is the root.

Comment: It doesn't make sense.  This is a custom tab bar controller, where the button for each tab is associated to one UINavigationController.  The point is to return them to the root view when you open a different tab.

Comment: You didnt explain your the point, you posted the error. Either way, `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` should return to the beginning of the stack. If you need a tab to return to a specific controller, tell the tab controller to do so, it's quite simple.

Comment: I don't need a tab to return to a specific controller...  I'm not sure what's not clear, but I don't think you understand.  Anyway, the suggestion of **Alexander N.** seems to have fixed the problem.  Thanks a lot for trying to help though!

Comment: Thats exactly what my answer was too, glad it helped!